# Unable to connect firebase to android project

Tags: android, firebase

I am using android studio 2.2.3 and am trying to connect my app to Firebase backend but I am unable to do so.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image: Firebase error]

I searched for the error 27, 13 and found answers asking to update the repositories and SDK. Having done both and cleaning and rebuilding the project I'm still having this error. Please help resolve this error.

[gradle:biuld file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esMNe.png)

Comment: Sorry, it looks like the link to your screenshot didn't post correctly. You will want to get that fixed before we are able to determine what the issue might be.

Comment: thanks for pointing out. i'll do it right away

Comment: It say I not yet allowed to embed images as i dont have 10 batches

Comment: Make sure you have downloaded and installed the Google Repository in your Android SDK Manager. I also recommend using the latest Firebase versions in Gradle as such: `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1`

Comment: I would suggest either uploading the image to a image hosting service (like Imgur) and linking to it. Someone with higher rep would be able to come in later and embed it for you. Or, you could copy the stack trace of the error (if there is one) and paste that into your question.

Comment: you should post your build.gradle file too..

Comment: tried both. still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps to install / update the Google Repository

- In Android Studio, navigate to the SDK Manager

  - From the toolbar: Tools > Android > SDK Manager
- Click SDK Tools and check Google Repository
- Hit OK to install

Also try updating your Firebase gradle dependencies to the latest version:

`com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1`

`com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1`

More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup, https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase.html

Comment: Of course! Consider marking the answer as correct to help people find it in the future

Comment: I already have the google repository, the dependencies in place. But still I am unable to connect to firebase in my android studio assistant.